# regarding transforming an ndarray(image input via cv2 or skimage) to a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I have read an image as follows using `opencv`

```
image = cv2.imread('/data/TestImages/cat.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

This read image cause the error message when it was called by `segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred, image, logits])`

The error message is as `TypeError: Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.`

Are there any mechanisms that can transform an image represented as ndarray to a Tensorflow tensor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read up on the sess.run function. In the array you have as argument of your function you specify what you want to get OUT of your run command. In your case, you probably only want your pred and logits.

If you want to put something IN the network you have to specify a tf.placeholder in your graph, and feed your image like this:

`np_pred,np_logits = sess.run([pred, logits],feed_dict={image_placeholder: image})`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi rmeertens, I changed the code as you suggested, but still get the error. I posted the related one in another thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356826/regarding-defining-input-placeholder-to-predict-over-a-given-image    Would you like to take a look at it? Thanks.