# Regarding defining input_placeholder to predict over a given image

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

In the following function, author aims to run prediction over a downloaded image based on vgg model.

```python
with tf.Graph().as_default():

url = ("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/First_Student_IC_school_bus_202076.jpg")

image_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)

image_float = tf.to_float(image, name='ToFloat')

# Subtract the mean pixel value from each pixel
processed_image = _mean_image_subtraction(image_float,
                                          [_R_MEAN, _G_MEAN, _B_MEAN])

input_image = tf.expand_dims(processed_image, 0)

with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):


    logits, _ = vgg.vgg_16(input_image,
                           num_classes=1000,
                           is_training=False,
                           spatial_squeeze=False)
pred = tf.argmax(logits, dimension=3)

init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
    os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, 'vgg_16.ckpt'),
    slim.get_model_variables('vgg_16'))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_fn(sess)
    segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred, image, logits])
```

I have been trying to predict over an existing image read via opencv, the only modification I made is to read image via cv2, add input_placeholder, and modify sess.run correspondingly. However, I got the following error message:

```python
segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred,logits],feed_dict={input_placeholder:image})
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Would you like to let me know which modification I made is wrong?

```python
with tf.Graph().as_default():

image = cv2.imread('/data/cat.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = [image.shape[0],image.shape[1],image.shape[2]])
image_float = np.float32(image)

# Subtract the mean pixel value from each pixel
processed_image = _mean_image_subtraction(image_float,[_R_MEAN, _G_MEAN, _B_MEAN])

input_image = tf.expand_dims(processed_image, 0)

with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):

    logits, _ = vgg.vgg_16(input_image,
                           num_classes=1000,
                           is_training=False,
                           spatial_squeeze=False)


pred = tf.argmax(logits, dimension=3)

init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
    os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, 'vgg_16.ckpt'),
    slim.get_model_variables('vgg_16'))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_fn(sess)
    segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred,logits],feed_dict={input_placeholder:image})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regarding transforming an ndarray(image input via cv2 or skimage) to a tensor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353188/regarding-transforming-an-ndarrayimage-input-via-cv2-or-skimage-to-a-tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference first take a look to the official documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run

For each graph element passed to the `fetches` parameter of `sess.run()` you get one value returned. In your case you are passing the following list as fetches: `[pred,logits]` so `sess.run([pred,logits], ...)` will return 2 values: the result of running the `pred` op and the `logits` op.

Citing the documentation

> The value returned by run() has the same shape as the fetches
>   argument, where the leaves are replaced by the corresponding values
>   returned by TensorFlow.

However in this line

`segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred,logits],feed_dict={input_placeholder:image})`

you are trying to assign these 2 values to 3 different python variables (`segmentation`, `np_image`, `np_logits`) hence you get the `ValueError`.

If you look at the original example you provided, the final line is:

`segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred, image, logits])`

To mimic the original example try removing the `np_image` declaration from your code like so:

`segmentation, np_logits = sess.run([pred,logits],feed_dict={input_placeholder:image})`

Answer (score 0):

is a python error:

```
segmentation, np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred,logits],feed_dict={input_placeholder:image})
```

should be

```
np_image, np_logits = sess.run([pred,logits],feed_dict={input_placeholder:image})
```

you are only passing two fetches to the run function

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. The problem is solved.